# How to update state (array of objects) with incoming object in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example, current state is:

```
    {
     data: [
      {id: 1, number: 100},
      {id: 2, number: 200},
      {id: 3, number: 300}
     ]
    }
```

Action is:

```
   const action = (id, number) => {
    return {id: id, number: number}
   }
```

How to implement reducer that it meets the following requirements:

1. If the state (array of objects) **doesn't have** an object with the same id as an incoming object - **push** the incoming object to the state;
2. If the state **has** an object with the same id as an incoming object - **update this object in state with number field value of an incoming object**.

***CASE 1:***

```
//incoming object
{id: 4, number: 400}

//result
    {
     data: [
      {id: 1, number: 100},
      {id: 2, number: 200},
      {id: 3, number: 300},
      {id: 4, number: 400}
     ]
    }
```

***CASE 2:***

```
//another incoming object
{id: 2, number: 250}

//result
    {
     data: [
      {id: 1, number: 100},
      {id: 2, number: 250},
      {id: 3, number: 300},
      {id: 4, number: 400}
     ]
    }
```

Maybe it has a simple solution, but I can't find the right approach to solving this problem:) Also I would like to know what is the best practice in cases like this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add logic to update or insert in your reducer.

Comment: Another approach that might be possible is to swap out the array you store in redux for a Record that uses the `id` of each object as a key. This means that checking an id exists is as simple as `!!data[id]` and assigning to it `data[id].number = 500;`. Depending on how complex the reducer is an what other actions it requires this could possibly be an option. The redux docs have [more information](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your action to use the `payload` property, but if you want you can remove it. (It's more proper to have it)

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_OR_INSERT':
      return {
        data: [
          ...state.data.filter(x => x.id !== action.payload.id),
          action.payload,
        ]
      }
     default:
  }
  return state;
}

console.log(
  reducer({
    data: [
      {id: 1, number: 100},
      {id: 2, number: 200},
      {id: 3, number: 300},
      {id: 4, number: 400}
     ]
    }, { type: 'UPDATE_OR_INSERT', payload: {id: 2, number: 250}}));
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as always filtering and appending is more optimal than a pre-search and branching logic. Though I will say that it is an *opinion* that it is it more proper to have a "payload" action property. I see many use-cases (pretty much all of them other than basic redux tutorials) where that just adds an unnecessary level of nesting.

Comment: So Brilliant. I love the elegant use of filter here.

Comment: @DrewReese it makes it hard to remove the `type` property when you want to add something to the state. (or you have to create a new object which is much better)

Comment: You should be more explicit with what is put into state. Use object destructuring to access the action properties you care about, and *copy* into a *new* object reference. This not only is easier to read and understand what data is being moved, and easier to maintain, it also protects against any rouge reducers that may accidentally mutate the action object, or worse by the UI because state also wasn't copied out.

Comment: @LLawliet Yes, payload property is preferred, sorry, it's my mistake. Thanks a lot for your elegant solution! But may I clarify: according to the documentation, we can only change the copy of the state (immutability). So is it possible to do so:
`return { ...state, data: [ ...state.data.filter(......).....]}`

Comment: @GlebBaeshko Yeah that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

How do you think of this solution?

```
const testState = {
    data: []
}

export default (state = testState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "SET_DATA":
            return [
                ...state.data.filter(d => d.id !== action.payload.id),
                action.payload,
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```